# Dynamic object allocation and propery access

Tags: .net, dynamic

I am developing one wcf client application. here i have 7 different requests.

is there any way to do like below demo code?

```
T obj =new anyobject ;

obj=DeSeriableXMLToObject<typeof(obj)>(string);

if(obj.property1=="200")
{
}
```

My deserialise function as below:

```
public static T DeSeriableXMLToObject<T>(string xml)
    {
// process for derisialising
}
```

i think , we can do this by dynamic in dot net. but i am new to this dynamic concept . could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my problem like below.

```
dynamic obj= new anyobject();

obj=DeSeriableXMLToObject(xml,obj);

if(obj.property1==200)
{
}
```

my deserialise function as like this;

```
dynamic DeSeriableXMLToObject(string xml,dynamic obj1) { 
//
Byte[] _bytes = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(xml);

DataContractSerializer datacontractser = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType ());

        object deserialized = _datacontractser .ReadObject(new MemoryStream(_bytes));

        return deserialized;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The deserialization would be something like:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
T obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(value));
```

Setting the property can be done in various ways. The preferred is to have some commonality between the types, perhaps an interface:

```
interface IFoo {
    string property1 { get; }
}
```

and:

```
T DeSeriableXMLToObject<T>(string value) where T : IFoo {
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(value));        
    if(obj.property1 == "200") { ...}
    return obj;
}
```

an alternative is reflection or `dynamic`:

```
T DeSeriableXMLToObject<T>(string value) {
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(value));        
    if(obj.property1 == "200") { ...}
    return obj;
}
```

btw; `DeSeriableXMLToObject<T>` looks... kinda funky as a name. May I suggest just `Deserialize<T>` or `DeserializeXml<T>` ?

Comment: can u post this using dynamic?

Comment: @Vetrivelmp like the last example?

Comment: T DeSeriableXMLToObject<T> in this function how to know T at run time ? for example you have to pass like DeSeriableXMLToObject<Class1>(). but I dont know whether that is class1 or class1 . how to write like this DeSeriableXMLToObject<DynamicType>() ? hope you understand my requirement.

Comment: @Vetrivelmp you'll have to know the `Type` in order to tell `XmlSerializer` how to work, but that doesn't mean you need to use generics. You could change it the the non-generic version passing in a `Type` as an input. But: you **do** need to know the actual `Type` to use `XmlSerializer`.